# When UTF8 emoji character is removed from NSMutableString the conversion to std::string fails

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I have an objective-c class which contains NSMutableString. The string represents a player name in an iOS game. I also have a std::string property in my implementation which contains the same data as NSMutableString:

```
{
@private
    std::string m_textCppString;
}
```

When I add characters to NSMutableString, I copy its contents to the std::string as well:

```
-(void)insertChar:(NSString *)c {
   [m_objcMutableStr appendString:c];
   m_textCppString = [m_objcMutableStr UTF8String];    
}
```

When I remove characters from NSMutableString, I also copy the contents of NSMutableString to the std::string:

```
- (void)deleteChar {
    if ([m_objcMutableStr length] > 0) {
        [m_objcMutableStr deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([m_objcMutableStr length]-1, 1)];
    }
    m_textCppString = [m_objcMutableStr UTF8String];
}
```

When I use normal latin alphabet characters, which fall into ASCII range these methods work well.

The insertion also works fine with UTF8 characters. Xcode debugger shows the smiley face or whatever emoji I am testing in `m_textCppString` with no problems.

However, when I remove an emoji character, the NSMutableStr is modified correctly but the conversion to std::string fails. The debugger stops in `string` class line 1370 with EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

`_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY basic_string& operator=(const value_type* __s) {return assign(__s);}`

If I try to convert the NSMutableString to const char*, it does not crash but returns NULL instead.

It almost seems that the `deleteCharactersInRange` method mangles NSMutableString in some way that it cannot be converted to std::string anymore. The odd thing is that this happens only when emojis (i.e. UTF8-specific chars) are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString assumes that strings are made of 16 bit units. For Emoji characters that is not true, they are made of two 16 bit units. If the last character of a string is an Emoji character, and you decrease the length by one, then you have a string ending in half an emoji character, which is not valid Unicode. From then on things will go wrong.

All the first 65536 Unicode code points will be fine. All code points from U10000 upwards (not just Emoji) will have problems. So your assumption is close and identifies the problem. It's just rarer than you thought which is both good and bad :-)